# How to trigger a JButton with a key press?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm trying to make it so that when the user presses the Enter key the `JButton` which is associated with that key gets triggered.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
      if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
          jButton2.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440209/how-do-i-assign-enter-as-the-trigger-key-of-all-jbuttons-in-my-java-application

Comment: BTW - this problem has *nothing* to do with the IDE, so don't add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to trigger a JButton with a key press?

Add an `ActionListener` to the button. It will fire an event when the button is in focus and the user presses the enter key. See [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more info.

### Edit

See also further details in Rob Camick's [Enter Key and Button](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/).

Comment: (1+) Definitely should be adding the ActionListener to the button (not a MouseListener). But the invoking of the Action when the Enter key is pressed can be a LAF issue. Check out [Button and Enter Key](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionListener` itself won't be sufficient. You will have to write a `KeyListener` to get this thing down. A `KeyListener` which captures Enter button press would look like this.

```
this.button.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter key pressed !");
        }

    }
});
```